# custom GitHub URL for Habitat?

Tags: chef-habitat

Is there a way to configure a custom GitHub URL for [Habitat](http://habitat.sh/)? For example, if my organization partners with GitHub to provide a private "instance" of GitHub. Looking at the [source](https://github.com/habitat-sh/habitat/blob/db0455d8a56976320b424f359eb045e2fe16dcbb/components/hab/src/config.rs#L76-L77), I only see directives for `auth_token` and `origin`. I realize Habitat is pretty new, so probably this will be a feature request; wanted to probe the hive mind before raising a PR :)

Comment: Removing the Chef tag as Habitat is unrelated to Chef.

Comment: my bad, thank you for catching that

Comment: No worries. You're welcome to ask this here but you're about 8000% more likely to get a timely response if you ask in the Habitat Slack team instead.

Comment: ahh, that's great advice -- thank you! i'll ask there and feed back into this question if i get an answer :D

Comment: asked question on [Habitat Slack](https://habitat-sh.slack.com/archives/general/p1474486943003121)

Comment: see also GitHub Isssue # [1042](https://github.com/habitat-sh/habitat/issues/1042) for support of non-GitHub OAuth backends. nolan@habitat-sh.slack.com has [suggested](https://habitat-sh.slack.com/archives/general/p1474490083003149) that "plugging in a URL to a GHE instance might just work", though it's new territory and ripe for testing. 
https://github.com/habitat-sh/habitat/blob/eeeec5340ecb7e0cc91f35809272309743cdc50f/components/builder-depot/src/config.rs#L25
https://github.com/habitat-sh/habitat/blob/cc4facdfe34d07890cacfb2a1925650598e03acc/components/builder-api/src/config.rs#L82